# BroadcastReceiver not receiving any data

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I use this code to send data to my `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
Log.d("recive message message message", message);

Intent resultBroadCastIntent = new Intent();
resultBroadCastIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
resultBroadCastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
resultBroadCastIntent.putExtra(OUTPUT_TEXT, message);

sendBroadcast(resultBroadCastIntent);
```

and the BroadcastReceiver code

```
public class Broadcast_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, Notification_Intent_Service.class));
    String resultText =intent.getStringExtra(Notification_Intent_Service.OUTPUT_TEXT);

    Log.d("recive dwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", resultText); 
    // this never run when message arrive
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".Service.Broadcast_Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

now in

```
Log.d("recive message message message", message);
```

the message is printed and I see it but it wasn't sent to the `BroadcastReceiver` or is it that the `BroadcastReceiver` didn't receive the data? I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: First, `resultBroadCastIntent` is an implicit `Intent`, and its action does not match that for which you've registered `Broadcast_Receiver`. Second, why don't you just start the `Service` directly, instead of broadcasting to a Receiver to do it?

Comment: @MikeM. i want service work if  phone restarted

Comment: That's fine, but that doesn't mean you _have_ to start the `Service` only from that Receiver. You can just as easily call `startService()` directly, after your `Log.d("recive...")` call. More easily, actually.

Comment: @MikeM. ok thanks for this Advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BOOT_COMPLETED` id when sending a broadcast

```
Intent resultBroadCastIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
resultBroadCastIntent.putExtra(OUTPUT_TEXT, message);
sendBroadcast(resultBroadCastIntent);
```

or Specify `SEND` action in `<intent-filter>`

```
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
</intent-filter>
```

Note: **Make sure your BroadcastReceiver isn't an Inner class** otherwise add static into it or move it in upper level.

Comment: i make them both no data received

Comment: As I look your naming convention `.Service.Broadcast_Receiver` it looks like Broadcast_Receiver is an inner class of Service.

Comment: no not inner class its just a package or folder (Service)

Comment: BTW packages should be small letters and class names should not have underscores by convention.

Comment: _not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED_

**i just try this**

 `resultBroadCastIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");`

Comment: i just remove `resultBroadCastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);`
and add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />`  in _manifest_ now its work

Answer (score 0):

You need to register Intent.ACTION_SEND for Broadcast receiver in manifest

```
 <receiver
     android:name=".Service.Broadcast_Receiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: i add it still same no data received